# Virtual address mangling for linux applications

Tags: linux, executable, elf

I am trying to understand the flow of different applications in Linux.

I traced the execution of two different programs (using Intel's pintool).

1. Hello world program written by me.
2. scp utility program.

The objdump of both programs show the instruction addresses in different ranges.

The execution trace (contains virtual addresses) of HelloWorld gives instruction addresses which can be seen in its objdump **whereas** the instruction addresses in the execution trace of scp are not to be seen in objdump of scp.

The scp application lies in /usr/bin directory. I observed similar anamoly with another application (ab - apache benchmark) located in /usr/bin.

Are the applications in those directory loaded specially ?
What could be the method to find the loading address of applications ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are the applications in those directory loaded specially

No.

It is likely that `scp` spends majority of its execution not inside the `scp` binary itself, but inside `libc.so.6` and the [vdso](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/vdso.7.html) (you should *still* see some instructions in the main binary though).

Another possible explanation is that `scp` on your distribution is built as position-independent executable (linked with `-pie` flag). You can prove or disprove that theory by looking at `readelf -h /usr/bin/scp` (look for file type, `ET_EXEC` vs. `ET_DYN`).

Update:

> readelf command says DYN (shared object file) for /usr/bin/scp

So my guess was correct, this is a position-independent binary.

> is there a way for me to determine the base address (while execution)

Sure: you could:

- look in `/proc/<pid-of-scp>/maps` for the first mapping of `/usr/bin/scp` with execute protections, or
- attach GDB to `scp` via `gdb -p <pid-of-scp>` and use `info file`, or
- teach your pin-tool to dump the mapping (`pin` is already tracing your process, so I believe you just need to print desired info on completion of `mmap`).

Comment: readelf command says DYN (shared object file) for /usr/bin/scp while it says EXEC (executable file) for helloworld.o. If /usr/bin/scp is a shared object file, is there a way for me to determine the base address (while execution) used for the functions listed in its objdump ??